# How to fix 400 Bad Request error?

Tags: c#

I'm getting a *The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request* error when trying to run my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    // Open request and set post data
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("myurl.com/restservice/Login");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset:utf-8";
    string postData = "{ \"username\": \"testname\" },{ \"password\": \"testpass\" }";

    // Write postData to request url
    using (Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
            sw.Write(postData);
    }

    // Get response and read it
    using (Stream s = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()) // error happens here
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        {
            var jsonData = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

**JSON EDIT**

Changed to:

```
{ \"username\": \"jeff\", \"password\": \"welcome\" }
```

But still not working.

**EDIT**

This is what I found that works:

```
       // Open request and set post data
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("myurl.com/restservice/Login");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    string postData = "{ \"username\": \"testname\", \"password\": \"testpass\" }";

    // Set postData to byte type and set content length
    byte[] postBytes = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

    // Write postBytes to request stream
    Stream s = request.GetRequestStream();
    s.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    s.Close();

    // Get the reponse
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    // Status for debugging
    string ResponseStatus = (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

    // Get the content from server and read it from the stream
    s = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // Clean up and close
    reader.Close();
    s.Close();
    response.Close();
```

Comment: Why are you mucking around with Streams? Use a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) instead!

Comment: WebClient is a good idea. But also, note that a 400 request usually denotes the server not understanding your request. A bad payload is the likely culprit, especially since you seem to have incorrect JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

can you try `string postData = "[{ \"username\": \"testname\" },{ \"password\": \"testpass\" }]";`

That way you are sending an array of 2 objects

**Edit**: Also maybe what you really want to send is just an object with 2 properties, then it would be `string postData = "{ \"username\": \"testname\", \"password\": \"testpass\" }"`

Comment: Many REST services return a HTTP 400 if the data is invalid, such as Viamenete and Palletways

Comment: Could the problem be the **postData**? It looks like it's sending the \ slashes literally.

Comment: I don't think that would be a problem they are just escape characters.. where are you seeing those slashes being sent?

Comment: In debug mode when I hover over postData.

Comment: Ok, debug mode will show you escaped-strings, but you can be sure they are being sent without slashes. So changing the json string didnt work?

Comment: Maybe I need another method of posting data & getting the response?

Comment: Maybe, try WebClient as @SpikeX recommended, i recommend you to use fiddler too http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ maybe you find a problem we are missing, if that doesn't work either then i would start looking for an issue in the server side

Comment: I have fiddler open. I never see the http request to myurl.com/restservice/Login. I only see my initial page load.

Comment: @jorgehmv I posted my solution

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though it may be coming from the JSON you are posting as it is invalid, see below what you are sending but in a valid form:

```
{
    "username": "testname",
    "password": "testpass"
}
```

Comment: As I said in my other comment, many REST services return a HTTP 400 if the data is invalid, such as Viamenete and Palletways. I have just today been working with a HTTP based web service that does this exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

postData is not a valid Json object

```
{ "username": "testname" },{ "password": "testpass" }
```

Try to use a Json parser like [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/), [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) instead of forming it manually